# Angular 4: Load vendor separately

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, websphere

currently I'm trying to figure out how to load the vendor seperatly from the build. Little backstory: Because of some constraints utilising Angular in Websphere Portal, we're including multiple Angular 4 apps into a single page. To keep the load times down I want to remove the vendor from each app and include it once in the parent page. Doing this results in an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at angular.vendor.js:1
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you won't run into more issues, but you should also move the `inline.bundle.js` to the parent page. In here the `webpackJsonp` function is defined

Comment: Tried to include that one and polyfill but without a succes. Now i get the following: Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 't' imported by the module 't'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: How are you loading multiple apps into one page?

Comment: It's done trough WebSphere Portal. It basically renders the whole build into a container on the webpage, per app.

Comment: and these apps are inside an iframe?

Comment: Nope, it strips the html, body tags away and inserts the html into the dom

Answer (score 0):

When you work with portlets on a page that need to share javascript framework(s) (which is what I presume you mean), you should leverage the Portal Theme modules and page Profiles to do so.

You add the thirdparty libraries to the theme and exclude these from the portlets.

If you're using Portal 8.5+, you can also have a look at script portlets; the above still holds, but script portlets do a better job at sandboxing each portlet's javascript (functions).

Comment: Hi Roan, thanks for your response. We are using script portlets in this case. I already tried to include everything but the main.js within the theme. Without success..

Comment: It might be the order in which scripts are loaded; play around with loading e.g. the main contributions in the Head section and the rest in the body section?